# cisco switch: port-security mac address sticky with an access point?

Tags: cisco

how can I secure a switchport where an access point is connected? 
Of course I can't use switchport port-security mac-address sticky otherwise my WLAN clients would not be able to connect. 
Or am I wrong an there is a way how to allow only a specified access point for that switchport? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Easiest method from a Cisco perspective would be with 802.1X or MAB with NAC like Cisco ISE or Aruba Clearpass. A limited feature/scalability NAC could be setup with Windows NPS or even the switch itself.

Comment: If interested in any of the limited options, I can post examples or links to them.